# call a function in google console

Tags: javascript, google-chrome

is there a way to call this function in the google console?
I am new to coding but I need this.

```
            e[dt.a.LUCKY_POT] = function(e) {
            return j.createElement(j.Suspense, {
                fallback: null
            }, j.createElement(bt, {
                onClose: function() {
                    return m(e)
                },
                notification: e,
                userId: null == d ? void 0 : d.id
            }))
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

you're basically assigning a function to a variable called `e[dt.a.LUCKY_POT]`
so just call `e[dt.a.LUCKY_POT]()`, but the question is what is the `e` object?
if you just want to run it and get the results - run the folloing:

```js
(function(e) {
            return j.createElement(j.Suspense, {
                fallback: null
            }, j.createElement(bt, {
                onClose: function() {
                    return m(e)
                },
                notification: e,
                userId: null == d ? void 0 : d.id
            }))
        })()
```

but then I'll ask who's the j object?